# Does GCP scheduled VM exits/loses its schedule when the VM is manipulated, stop/start, manualy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, schedule

I have previously scheduled my VM (**e2-micro** in *europe-central2-a*)  succesfully. It has a schedule assigned to start and stop at certain hours... in order to save machine use time at night. It worked until I stopped the instance manually from *CLI* for some work.

Since that, the schedule is not forcing the instance to Start-Stop and I have to do it manually.

Now, The machine is working fine, no issues, But it doesn't resume/return to said schedule previously set if I stop-start it manually (for some manual work through ssh-connection). Is there a specific procedure (maybe I missed some instructions for the case) to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "its schedule"?

Comment: I mean the applied Instance Schedule. it has a schedule assigned to start and stop at certain hours... and save machine time at night. It worked untill I stoped the instance manualy from CLI for some work. Since than the schedule is not forcing the intance to Start-Stop and I have to do it manualy. I was wondering why is that

Comment: Are you sure that your schedule is still valid (no end date)? Did you check if your VM is still in the schedule?

Comment: Yes, the Scheduler is well formed and valid, BUT, I figured it out: after my manual stop-restart, the Scheduler, I checked, had lost the attched VM. So I had to attach the VM again. I'm not confident, but it may have been my mistake, I don't remember well attaching the VM in first place.